# How can I stop fseventsd for certain volumes?

Tags: unix, kernel, macos

I also have a partion with Ubuntu installed. Unfortunately, every time I have an error while working on the Ubuntu partion (I believe it's ext3), I get a Kernel Panic and I have to restart. I believe this is related to fseventsd, since it my try to log the errors on the root of the Ubuntu partition.

How can I stop fseventsd logging events on that Ubuntu volume?

Thank you!

Comment: There's been some confusion about this question and how it relates to Mac OS X. As I understand it, the Mac process `fseventsd` is messing up your Ubuntu partition and causing kernel panics, and your question is how to tell Mac OS X to stop fseventsd logging for a particular volume. Is that correct? If so, this question is on topic for Ask Different.

Comment: Yes Nathan, I need to stop that process from logging errors for my Ubuntu partition. I believe it might be a conflict of permissions that causes this kernel panics whenever I am working in the terminal on the Ubuntu partition, and I get an error message (stderr).

Comment: [Canonical question](/q/6707) for other cruft.

Answer (score 9):

## Preventing file system event storage

Whilst you should not stop the daemon, you can disable logging on a per-volume basis.

### In the Mac Developer Library

[File System Events Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Conceptual/FSEvents_ProgGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40005289-CH1-SW1): [File System Event Security](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Conceptual/FSEvents_ProgGuide/FileSystemEventSecurity/FileSystemEventSecurity.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40005289-CH6-SW1): [Preventing File System Event Storage](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Conceptual/FSEvents_ProgGuide/FileSystemEventSecurity/FileSystemEventSecurity.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40005289-CH6-SW5) advises:

> … To disable logging on a per-volume basis (for creating a backup
>   volume, for example), you must do the following:
>
> - Create a `.fseventsd` directory at the top level of the volume.
> - Create an empty `no_log` file in that directory.
>
> So if your volume is mounted at `/Volumes/MyDisk`, you would create an
>   empty file called `/Volumes/MyDisk/.fseventsd/no_log`.

---

## Kernel panics

Please consider creating a separate question.

Comment: Ten years later... the page still exists on Apple.com, but the `no_log` file appears to no longer be honored by `fseventsd`.

Answer (score 1):

OS X does not have a built-in ext3 driver so it's not possible to even access the Ubuntu partition from OS X.

There is a lot of information missing here making it impossible to correctly assess what is causing your kernel panic.

Are you even using Apple hardware?

Comment: Yes, I am using Apple hardware. In order to access ext4 (Ubuntu partition) I'm using 3rd party driver from Paragon (Paragon ExtFS). From what I understand, the fseventsd process writes error logs on the root of the partition that you are working on. So, let's say I am working in terminal on the ubuntu partition, once receive and error message there, I get my kernel panic. I need to know how can I stop this process to stop logging error messages for my Ubuntu partition.